# How can I set this sumValue to JTextField, because it doesn't show anything

Tags: java

The code below takes two integers as input, and stores them as `firstNumber` and `secondNumber`. However, when pressing `equalsButton` nothing happens.

```
    public class PlusButtonActionListener implements ActionListener {

      private double firstNumber;
      private double secondNumber;
      private double sumVal;
      MathOperationsClass mathOperationsClass;

      @Override
      public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        firstNumber = Double.parseDouble(MainFrame.textField.getText());
          if(e.getSource() == MainFrame.getPlusButton()) {
            if(!MainFrame.textField.equals("")) {
              MainFrame.textField.setText("");
        } else {
          secondNumber = Double.parseDouble(MainFrame.textField.getText());
              if(e.getSource() == MainFrame.getEqualsButton()) {
                sumVal = mathOperationsClass.sum(firstNumber, secondNumber);
                MainFrame.textField.setText(String.valueOf(sumVal));
          }
        }
      }
  }
}
```

Comment: because that's `PlusButtonAcitonListener` ?

Comment: "Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: How to create a [mcve]"

Comment: Yes, but I set it to equalButton too.